# I need to access a Google Maps API Marker from a menu item

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a

```
Marker nlb1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions())
```

Inside of a SetUpMap() void and I need to .remove() this inside of a onOptionsItemSelected boolean. How do I go about doing that?

How can I make the Marker nlb1 go global? Should I declare it in like the beginning of the app like a global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think if you want to use the `object` in `different methods` in the `same class`, define a `member variable` is a good idea.

Sample code:

```
Marker mNlb1; //m stands for member or global variable
```

in the method:

```
mNlb1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions());
```

Comment: Yup, that did it. I made the markers as global variables and just put the methods in them using them as mNlb1.setVisibility() etc etc.

Thank you so much